# Android activity freezing, need assistance interpreting log

Tags: android, logcat, ddms

These events have recently been linked to the call `mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);`

Hey guys, been working on this app for a while now and every now-and-then it will simply freeze on me, sometimes returning normally and others simply crashing out (sometimes literally crashing the phone, making me reboot). It only happens roughly every 1/5 attempts, and it was actually hard for me to catch with DDMS for some reason because it simply wouldn't glitch while I was trying to log/profile it.

I've since logged the activity below throughout the freeze with DDMS. Any help with this log would be much appreciated, if I happen to come across my solution in the mean time I'll post back. Thanks in advance!

```
04-15 05:14:03.154: WARN/SharedBufferStack(4148): waitForCondition(DequeueCondition) timed out (identity=355, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-15 05:14:04.154: WARN/SharedBufferStack(4148): waitForCondition(DequeueCondition) timed out (identity=355, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-15 05:14:05.154: WARN/SharedBufferStack(4148): waitForCondition(DequeueCondition) timed out (identity=355, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-15 05:14:06.154: WARN/SharedBufferStack(4148): waitForCondition(DequeueCondition) timed out (identity=355, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-15 05:14:07.154: WARN/SharedBufferStack(4148): waitForCondition(DequeueCondition) timed out (identity=355, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-15 05:14:08.123: INFO/ActivityThread(4148): Removing dead content provider: settings
04-15 05:14:08.154: WARN/SharedBufferStack(4148): waitForCondition(DequeueCondition) timed out (identity=355, status=0). CPU may be pegged. trying again.
04-15 05:14:08.186: DEBUG/SensorManager(4148): _sensors_data_poll() failed, we bail out.
```

Using accelerometer, touch, and capturing keys as well. All of this while using a `canvasThread` to do my drawing from a `surfaceView`. All of which is "separated" from the UI thread.

Have been trying to get a stack trace off the crash, but when I attach the debugger to it the darn thing won't glitch on me; it does however seem to get data from the accelerometer at almost half the rate? Any idea why this is?

**[EDIT]** --- *Finally got a stack trace*

```
Thread [<9> CanvasThread] (Suspended)   
    **Surface.unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas) line: not available [native method]** 
    SurfaceView$3.unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas) line: 804 
    CanvasSurfaceView$CanvasThread.run() line: 233  


Thread [<8> AsyncQueryWorker] (Suspended)   
    **Object.wait(long, int) line: not available [native method]**  
    MessageQueue(Object).wait() line: 288   
    MessageQueue.next() line: 146   
    Looper.loop() line: 123 
    HandlerThread.run() line: 60    


Thread [<7> Binder Thread #2] (Suspended)   
    **NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]**   


Thread [<6> Binder Thread #1] (Suspended)   
    **NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]**   

Daemon System Thread [<5> Compiler] (Suspended) 
    NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]   

Daemon System Thread [<3> Signal Catcher] (Suspended)   
    NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]   

Daemon System Thread [<2> HeapWorker] (Suspended)   
    NativeStart.run() line: not available [native method]
```

**New information**, while using DDMS I tried hitting "Stop Process" when it freezes, and it kills the app for a second after which it reappears and continues without hesitation... wierd

Comment: It would be interesting to see the code that causes this problems.

Comment: @Roflcoptr I usually say the same thing to people, but the code is roughly 12 different .java files with anywhere from 200 - 800 lines of code in each? Where to start... I'm just seeing if anyone can offer any information on the mentioned errors? Or possibly a discussion of similar issues, which I've yet to find. Like what are the cases that a _sensors_data_poll will fail? I can't seem to find much documentation on this anywhere. Understandable if this is too vague tho.

Comment: Does this happen only while running your app, or even other apps?

Comment: @Rajath Only when running this app, all other apps (and the phone) work just fine for everything else. I'm also implementing a canvasThread. Plus another note is that I'm restricting orientation to portrait so I don't think it has anything to do with orientation changes either (as I first thought).

Comment: What sensors are you using, if at all?

Comment: Accelerometer and Touch.

Comment: Does it crash at a specific location? That is, does it crash when you do a certain thing (like starting a new Activity) or is it "all over"?

Comment: @While-E ah ok i see, I thought it always crashes at a specific position (i.e. when you do something specific)

Comment: Nope, not freezing at specific locations, sometimes it will work perfectly as it should. It will literally freeze at random spots during activity loop, uncontrollable to me. I'm probably going to try to start blocking out code soon to try to find a solution.

Comment: @While-E Is it an old G1 phone? There I noticed the same problem on four different G1 devices while using the motion sensor.

Comment: @Roflcoptr it's actually a Droid2

Comment: Could it be the problem of this issue? http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15170&q=removeUpdates&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars